# Trapezoid area is 34, find k.

Tags: geometry

I have the problem:[image]
and I was wondering how I would complete the problem. I have graphed it using geogebra, an online graphing calculator. Note that k and m are currently set to 3.1 and 6.1 randomly, and CD is not necessarily perpendicular to $y=-x+4$ as the problem states it is supposed to be.

Can someone help me solve the problem? I would prefer to not use a program to run through several possibilities and get the answer and hopefully not brute force, as there is supposed to be a clean answer for this one, but for now, any help is appreciated. (Also, please don't just give the answer, I want to gain something from this.)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slopes of perpendicular lines are negative reciprocals, so you are given that the slope of $CD$ is $+1$.  Use that to find one relation between $m$ and $k$.  The altitude of your trapezoid is $4$, so what should the sum of the bases be?  With your relation between $m$ and $k$ you now have two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: Thank you! I think I will be able to use this to complete the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Shoelace formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/triangles-calculating-area/#area-of-triangles-shoelace-formula) to obtain:

$$ 34 = \frac12 \begin{vmatrix}
-1 & k & m & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 4 & 4 & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix} \Rightarrow m + k = 16 \tag1 $$

The gradient of the straight line must be the negative reciprocal of the gradient of the given straight line,

$$ - \dfrac1{-1} = \dfrac{4-0}{m-k} \Rightarrow m - k = 4 \tag2$$

Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives $(m,k) = (10,6)$.